# How to insert multi-line element into XML file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have file with text like

```
<xml>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<x></x>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

I want to add a new `<plugin>...</plugin>` entry into it. 
How to do it?

Using simple string replacement might have issues as the entry to be added is something like

```
 <cordova-plugin id="c6" pluginId="someid"
                      path="./somepath/">
         <platform id="p2" name="android" enabled="true"/>
         <platform id="p4" name="ios" enabled="true"/>
      </cordova-plugin>
   </cordova-plugins>
```

Comment: so you want to add your new text just before `</plugins>`..right?

Comment: Is `</plugins>`the last line in you file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `i` insert command of `sed` to insert it at line `.

```
$ cat file
<xml>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<x></x>
</plugin>
</plugins>
$ sed '/<\/plugins>/ i  <cordova-plugin id="c6" pluginId="someid" path="./somepath/"> \
<platform id="p2" name="android" enabled="true"/> \
<platform id="p4" name="ios" enabled="true"/> \
</cordova-plugin> \
</cordova-plugins>' file
<xml>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<x></x>
</plugin>
<cordova-plugin id="c6" pluginId="someid" path="./somepath/"> 
<platform id="p2" name="android" enabled="true"/> 
<platform id="p4" name="ios" enabled="true"/> 
</cordova-plugin> 
</cordova-plugins>
</plugins>
$
```

Since you need to put escapes(`\`) for every new line, instead you can use a normal `bash` loop to read line by line and output inserted contents when you encounter your line:

```
$ cat file
<xml>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<x></x>
</plugin>
</plugins>
$ cat insert
<cordova-plugin id="c6" pluginId="someid"
                      path="./somepath/">
         <platform id="p2" name="android" enabled="true"/>
         <platform id="p4" name="ios" enabled="true"/>
      </cordova-plugin>
   </cordova-plugins>
$ while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
> do
> [[ "$line" =~ \</plugins\> ]] && cat insert
> echo "$line"
> done  < "file"
<xml>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<x></x>
</plugin>
<cordova-plugin id="c6" pluginId="someid"
                      path="./somepath/">
         <platform id="p2" name="android" enabled="true"/>
         <platform id="p4" name="ios" enabled="true"/>
      </cordova-plugin>
   </cordova-plugins>
</plugins>
$
```

Just save the output to a new file by putting `> newfile` after the loop.